# asp.net mvc4 : publishing issue due to System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Im working on a asp.net mvc4 application, witch is working fine. So i've decided to deploy it, i managed to publish correctly my app (permission and connection strings working). my problem is an annoying 500 Internal Server Error witch I think I understand :
 Im making an ajax call to an action "LocalFiles" witch is responsable for browsing a directory named "\Exe" in my app root folder, witch contains files. here is the action :

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult LocalFiles()
    {
        DirectoryInfo folder = new DirectoryInfo(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Exe\\");

        List<FileObject> list = new List<FileObject>();

        //here it performs the browsing

        return Json(list);
    }
```

when i work "offline" using the iisexpress `System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` works fine and returns "C:\Users\DaFriskyMonkey\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\MainProject\MainProject". BUT when it comes to publishing iis doesnt recognize this path : "Could not find a part of the path "C:\Users\DaFriskyMonkey\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\MainProject\Exe", this is normal because the "Exe" folder is not in the  "\MainProject\" but in "\MainProject\MainProject\".
How can I modify my action in order to make it browsing the correct folder.

Im sorry if my question is a bit complicated, if you need more details just ask.

Thanks very much.

Comment: if i copy and paste "\Exe" in the parent folder "\MainProject", it works, but this is resolving the problem without resolving it :), any ideas please ??

Comment: Have you tried using Server.MapPath("~/Exe") or System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Exe")?